# Moving to the mouse position on mouse-click

Tags: unity, input

I am migrating my projects to the new input system in Unity.
I have a project in which the user can point the mouse anywhere on the screen, then click the mouse button, and the player moves to the mouse position. I am trying to implement it using [embedded actions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/manual/Workflow-Embedded.html), without referring to specific controls in the code. What I have so looks like this:

```
public class ClickMover : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    InputAction moveHere; 

    ...

    void Update() {
        if (moveHere.WasPressedThisFrame()) {
            Vector2 mousePositionInScreenCoordinates = moveHere.ReadValue<Vector2>();  
            Vector3 mousePositionInWorldCoordinates = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePositionInScreenCoordinates);
            mousePositionInWorldCoordinates.z = transform.position.z;
            transform.position = mousePositionInWorldCoordinates;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Unity Editor, I see the "move here" action, and can choose its type. I chose `Vector2` so that I can get the mouse position. But now, I do not have a way to listen to the mouse-click.

Can I have Unity listen to the mouse click, and then give me the mouse position, in a single `InputAction`?

Comment: A button being pressed and the location of a pointer are two separate inputs. Do you encounter any problems treating the "here" and the "move" as two input actions?

Comment: @DMGregory This works, thanks. I just thought there should be a way to treat it as a single input action, since logically it is a single action - move to a specific location.

Comment: A single logical action can still be two discrete inputs, like "Run over there" being both a directional input "over there" and an intensity/break-stealth decision "run" in Assassin's Creed games. Keeping the two inputs separate is helpful for remapping for accessibility: say a player is using eye tracking for the directional part and a puff switch to execute the movement. If you have a compelling need to combine these into a single input in code, please edit your question to explain and we can potentially design a custom composite input; but if not, is there anything else you need help with?

Comment: Being able to separate "here" from "move" also helps you support "on hover" actions like updating a cursor state, showing a preview of the move to be made, or offering contextual information. You lose that if the position information is unavailable until a player "performs" the move action.

Comment: @DMGregory OK. Thanks!